# Comparing user input with PHP array

Tags: php

For a small project I'm working on I want a user to be able to register an account using a username however I don't want to configure a database i.e I just want to compare the username the user inputs with a PHP array.

```
<?php
$a=array("user1","user2");
for($a =0; $x<$arrlength; $a++){
if($username == $a){ //i want to say if $username is in array alert this and do nothing
$echo print a new username, already taken;
return false;
else(
array_push($a,username);?>
```

I'm working with the w3 schools PHP examples and I have something like this (the user inputs a 'username' in a form. I was wondering how you would actually implement this functionality properly.

Comment: You would still need to store the user list somewhere if you want to permanently store the user. A database is the best way. But if you really don't want to use a database, then you would have to store it in a flat text file. You could do something like `file_put_contents('users.txt', serialize($a))` at the end of the file to store the contents of $a in users.txt. Then in the beginning of the file you would do `$a=unserialize(file_get_contents('users.txt'));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use the `in_array()` function:

```
<?php
$usernames = array("user1", "user2", "user3", "user4");

if (in_array("username_from_user_input", $usernames)) {
    echo "Got Username";
}else{
    echo "Username not found"
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks George that's what i was looking for and it makes sense. It's only a small little test i'm doing (i'm new to PHP) for myself thanks for the help!

Comment: Sometimes the simplest answer is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save the registered accounts across requests, you have to store them in a file or database (or something else..), because the script is run from start on every requests.

Instead of looping over the array, you could also use the in_array function. ( http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php )

To store the usernames, take a look at the file functions. (e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php to write to a file, and file_get_contents or file(..) to read a file). (*For real projects, make sure to lock the file to prevent race conditions.*)

Comment: S/he should also consider blocking access to the file on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but because I'm on a [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) mood, here it goes:

```
echo (in_array("someuser", array("user1","user2"))) ? "Got Username" : "Username not found";
```

Comment: Got my vote as it's a valid alternative (not to mention I love ternary too ;-))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in_array`:

```
if (in_array($username, $a){
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution of the other users but you could combine with Traits.

You could create a **Trait** called `VerifyUser` with the next content:

```
trait VerifyUser {
    public function verifyUser($user){
        if (in_array($username, $usersArray)){
            echo $username . "is already taken";
        }else {
            array_push($usersArray, $username);
        }
    }
}
```

> Don't forget add your custom array to your class if you are working in a OOP environment. Add this trait with the `use VerifyUser` instruction.

```
class UsersCollection{
    use VerifyUsers

    $usersArray= ["user1", "user2"];

    $this->verifyUser("user1"); //It echo the custom message you could return a boolean value and then specify a custom behaviour.
}
```

Comment: I think this is way too advanced for someone new to PHP.

Comment: Correct, but I only answered this need and may be useful for other users newbies or advanced. The answer is use the `in_array` function but I only exposed a way to improve this, facilitating the code reusability.